# How to tag user to a pic via php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code. It does not do anything. :(

```
$post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$photo_id."/tags/".$random_friend['id']."?access_token=".$access_token."&x=22&y=22&method=POST";   

 $response = file_get_contents($post_url);
```

I have defined everything.. but it still not works.
I want to know how to tag user or his friends in a pic uploaded by my app.

I am using all necesarry permissions required.
user_photos, friends_photos, publish_stream

Comment: Output the value of $post_url, and test it in your browser first.

Comment: Don’t you know how to print out the contents of a string variable …?

Comment: Ohh.. I got it :P
U mean to use echo/print
I have printed it. And when i go to that link which has my access token and other details. It tags me in that picture. But How to do that in php sdk ? Please help :(

Comment: When i printed $post_url 
it gave this link.

https://graph.facebook.com/109948522500769/tags/100004304380055?access_token=AAACaS4jjle8BAIZC3r00jnBpxyQtMG9jefHiPNc7wyzyuIlpzZCNbttwxGqaT0p1rBGgB7qgSN82QZCUvQ8qkNbPnon9bbFQnzVAxC4gQZDZD&x=22&y=22&method=POST

and it tagged my friend in the pic whose pic id i have given.

but when i printed $response it was empty.

What does that mean?

Comment: Using file_get_contents its hard to find out what might cause an error. You should use the PHP SDK instead, it’ll give you “nice” error messages in form of an exception if something goes wrong.

Comment: Please give me the code for that .. please! 

I am just learning everything... ! please help